# I have a resource named Image in a Rails app. How can I access the dynamically generated path helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The important one in question is `MODELNAME_path`, which in this case would be `image_path`, but this seems to clash with the existing method in `ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper`.

I'm currently calling `image_path(@image)` in an RSpec view spec file, and it's taking me, reasonably, to the method in `AssetTagHelper` and raising an exception, since I'm trying to pass it an object when it ordinarily takes a string.

My first instict was to try `url_for`, but this, most curiously (and I can't figure out the reason for this one; feel free to enlighten me), eventually just delegates the work back to `AssetTagHelper.image_tag`. Weird.

So the bottom line question is how I should go about specifically calling the dynamically defined `image_tag`, and in general how to differentiate the two.

This is the last time I ever name a resource Image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried polymorphic_path(@image) instead of image_path(@image) ?

Answer (score 0):

Rails actually recommends you use path_to_image for this exact issue.